# Enable submit button if atleast one field has filled value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry this might be a duplicate Q , but could not find a direct solution easily,

I have gone through SO answer and found , enable `submit` if all values are filled ,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.field input').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('.field input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('.actions input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('.actions input').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

But how to achieve the same(enable submit) if atleast one field is non-empty

Comment: Add an else part to `if ($(this).val().length == 0) { empty = true; } else { break; }`

Comment: In else part add `empty = false` and `break;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.field input').keyup(function() {
        var hasValue = $('#username,#password').filter((index, input) => input.value.length > 0).length;
    
        $('.actions input').attr('disabled', hasValue ? false : 'disabled');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

Update:

```
$('#username,#password').filter((index, input) => input.value.length > 0).length
```

This line means we will check the value of the 2 input elements `username` and `password`, if all of them don't have any value, the button will be disabled. If you want to check another input element before enabling/disabling, you can add:

```
$('#username,#password,#input_3,#input_4').filter(...).length
```

By this way, the button will be disabled when `username`, `password`, `input_3` and `input_4` elements don't have any value. Make sure you have a specific id for each input element.

---

Update 2:

Checking for both `username` and `password` have some value:

```
var hasValue = $('#username,#password').filter((index, input) => input.value.length > 0).length === 2
```

Checking for `field`, `field4` and `field5` have some value:

```
var hasValue = $('#field,#field4,#field5').filter((index, input) => input.value.length > 0).length === 3
```

Comment: This is charm thanks mate, could i achieve the same for multiple fields like ? for example i have 5 inputs , for combinations of 2 and 4 , 3 and 5 .....i need to enable or else still in disable

Comment: Does this not present an issue when both fields are filled and then one of the fields is emptied?

Comment: Not working. Type in both fields and then clear one input, it again goes to diable. See my answer.

Comment: @Codenewbie Yes. You can do the same thing by editting selectors `$('.actions input')`, just add another line with the specific ids

Comment: @Tân could you please provide a basic example for my another question? some random input and select fields , and combinations as asked in comment

Comment: @Codenewbie I've updated my answer. You can check again.

Comment: @Tân  sorry It was n't well explained by me, the solution you gave me was easy understandable, but i want something here like , usually `and` in programming ----  if `username` & `password` , if `field` & `field4` & `field5` enable button else still disabled , hope it is clear now?

Comment: @Codenewbie You mean: If both `username` and `password` have some value, enable the button. Another, if `field` and `field4` and `field5` have some value, enable the button. Not just one. Right?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tân , now I would work on mix of these all on my own , would ask if i stuck anywhere

Comment: @Tân I am surprised that the same doesn't work for a select when i tried ` $('.form-group input,.form-group select').keyup(function()......` is this wrong?

Comment: @Codenewbie It should be another question. It looks like you're defining [keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event for `<select>` tag. That's wrong. So, if you have new question, you can post it.

Comment: you mean using a keyup for select is wrong? , any alternative please, it would be a mess if I can't use the keyup

Comment: @Tân I am looking for your best answer for this sir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59609687/enable-submit-button-if-atleast-one-field-has-filled-value-or-a-selected-dropd/59609811?noredirect=1#comment105383380_59609811

Answer (score 1):

You could with `Jquery.map` and `Array.find`

1. `Jquery.map().get()` is get all the input value length with condition.
2. `Array.find` will find the any one of the input as valid length of string
3. Then finally the result will be reversely compare `prop('disabled', !filled)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.field input').keyup(function() {
    var res = $('.field input').map(function() {
        return $(this).val().length != 0
    }).get()
    var filled  = res.find(a=> a == true)
    $('.actions input').prop('disabled', !filled);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Updated with select option**

Required field based .Button only enabled after required field 1 and 3 both are filled

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.field input,.field select').on('keyup change',function() {
    var res = $('.field input[required],.field select[required]').map(function() {
      return $(this).val().trim().length != 0
    }).get();
    var filled = res.every(a => a == true)
    $('.actions input').prop('disabled', !filled);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="username">Username *</label>
      <input id="username" required type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="password">email *</label>
      <input id="password" required type="password" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="password">select email *</label>
      <select required>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: sir, how would i use the same for <select> tag too?, is this possible?

Comment: @Codenewbie .yes of-course .You could add select  elem in the jquery selector `$('.field input[required],.field select[required]')` .Check my latest updated answer

Comment: I have been trying this https://jsfiddle.net/05em7jh2/ .....I am trying to disable the submit button when these combinations are selected 1) wordtype and word 2) wordlength + word 3) wordlength + wordtype + word

Comment: could you please look at the fiddle

Comment: @Codenewbie please clarify .. when you enable the button? only position button was missing

Comment: I want to enable for all selections except for this mate 1) wordtype and word 2) wordlength + word 3) wordlength + wordtype + word ....

Comment: when any one of the above combination are inside the selection result that button was disabled right ? ex `combination (1,3), sel =[1,2,3] is disabled | sel=[1,2] is enabled`

Comment: It's (1,3),(1,3,4),(3,4) .....for this combinations it must be disabled

Comment: @Codenewbie Let check this solution https://jsfiddle.net/qzwyevtp/1/

Comment: It should work , when i select all, but it is not mate

Comment: @Codenewbie yes right .because if you select all. Above 3 combination are satisfied this condition

Comment: but that is different from all right, (1,2,3,4) is not equal to (1,3,4) or any other combination

Comment: almost got mate but (2,3,4) should work mate....found this at this time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205433/discussion-between-codenewbie-and-prasanth).

Comment: sir, why this doesn't work for the second time , i hit search and when I am trying again it is not working

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: This is because I am rendering new template which is a block of main template

Comment: @Codenewbie check jquery link present or not

Comment: The think is i should add jquery link in <head> instead of outside of <body> which i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery props method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
     $('input').keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
           $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }else{
          $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
        }
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the sol sir,  could i achieve the same for multiple fields like ? for example i have 5 inputs , for combinations of 2 and 4 , 3 and 5 .....i need to enable or else still in disable

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go about it:

Store the fields, and create a new collection of them each time a key is pressed, filtering each one by its value.

If the length of our empty fields is the same as the length of all fields, disable the button:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $fields = $('.field input');
    
    $fields.keyup(function() {

        var $emptyFields = $fields.filter(function(){
            return !this.value;
        });
        
        $('.actions input').prop('disabled', $emptyFields.length === $fields.length);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Documentation:**

- [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)
- [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in a simple way, as shown below:

```
var filled = false;
$('.field input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
                filled = true;
                return;     // just add return means break from loop whenever any field is filled. 
            }
        });

        if (filled) {
            $('.actions input').attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('.actions input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
```