# Enable submit button if atleast one field has filled value / or a selected dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<select>` tag along with `<input>`, as below, but it doesn't work.

How can I enable the submit button if at least one field has a value or a selected option? How can I enable the submit button on multiple (`and/&` in general) fields selection?

Any help is appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.field input,.field select').keyup(function() {
    var hasValue = $('#username,#password,#position').filter((index, input, select) => input.value.length > 0).length;

    $('.actions input').attr('disabled', hasValue ? false : 'disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <select id="position">
        <option value="">position</option>
        <option value="1">first</option>
        <option value="2">second</option>
        <option value="3">third</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The only thing that's not working is the change of the `select` because you're using the `keyup` event. Change to `on('input change', ...` instead and your code will work fine

Comment: No , it doesn't for just a select dropdown

Comment: Exactly , looking for any alternative to achieve the same mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `input` and `change` on the `form`, rather than `keyup` on the fields, since of course you can pick things with the mouse. I'd also use `prop`, not `attr`, to set `disabled`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on("input change", function() {
    var hasValue = $('#username,#password,#position').filter((index, input, select) => input.value.length > 0).length;

    $('.actions input').prop('disabled', !hasValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <select id="position">
        <option value="">position</option>
        <option value="1">first</option>
        <option value="2">second</option>
        <option value="3">third</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Separately, I think I'd probably use a more general selector when selecting the fields to check, and stop the check as soon as I know I need to enable the form:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on("input change", function() {
    var hasValue = false;
    $(this).find("input[type=text], input[type=password], select").each(function() {
      if (this.value) {
        hasValue = true;
        return false;
      }
    });
    $(this).find('.actions input').prop('disabled', !hasValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <select id="position">
        <option value="">position</option>
        <option value="1">first</option>
        <option value="2">second</option>
        <option value="3">third</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, looking for combination of selections made too as per my 2) in Q?

Comment: @Codenewbie - Looks like you must have figured it out...? (Since you accepted the answer.) :-)

Comment: @Codenewbie You don't need my answer here because this answer is enough for you. If your second requirement means: Checking for both `username` and `password` have some value **and** the dropdown has a selected value. In the line `var hasValue = $('#username,#password,#position').....`, you can add `=== 3` after `.length`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I can only think your reputation made him pressed the accepted button *(An expert cannot be wrong)* lol

Comment: I am tricked here when I am applying the same on this code https://jsfiddle.net/zbxsqLh7/ , I am trying to disable the submit button when ,these combinations are selected 1) wordtype and word 2) wordlength + word 3) wordlength + wordtype + word

Comment: I could not figure it how to do that, as there are 3 conditions applied at once , can you help with that fiddle please...TIA

Comment: @Codenewbie - I'm afraid I can't understand what you want in the above. If it were me, I'd want to enable the Login button when username and position had selected values, ignoring whether password did (although having a blank password is probably not a good idea). Is that what you want to do?

Comment: I am trying to apply the same , on my own example here https://jsfiddle.net/zbxsqLh7/.....I am trying to disable the submit button when ,these combinations are selected 1) wordtype and word 2) wordlength + word 3) wordlength + wordtype + word

Comment: @Codenewbie Make sure you've tested it **correctly** before asking. In your fiddle, I see that you're still using `.change(...)` instead of `.on('input change')`. And you're calling selectors `$('#username,#password,#position')` while your html doesn't have, it should be `$('#wordlength,#word,#position,#wordtype').......length === 4`. That's your fault.

Comment: @Codenewbie - I'm confused, why would you **disable** the button when wordtype and word are selected? Rather than thinking in terms of when to disable it, I would suggest thinking in terms of when to **enable** it.

Comment: Sorry, Enabling conditions are much more, but disabling conditions are less (3) , so would want to disable instead

Comment: @Tân yeah sir, that's my fault it didn't update in the fiddle my bad, here is the updated one https://jsfiddle.net/ovz8w2my/1/       ,I am trying to disable the submit button when these combinations are selected 1) wordtype and word 2) wordlength + word 3) wordlength + wordtype + word

Comment: @Codenewbie - You're **still** just using `change`, not `input`. You're still using `attr`, not `prop`. As for the conditions, your three boil down to: "Disable when word has a value and either wordtype or wordlength has a value)," so: `$('.actions input').prop('disabled', $("#word").val() && ($("#wordtype").val() || ($("#wordlength").val()));`

Comment: could not sort out the solution mate, can you please send me a fiddle attached solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **change** event instead of the keyup

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( '.field input,.field select' ).change(function() {
   var hasValue = $('#username,#password,#position').filter((index, input, select) => input.value.length > 0).length;

    $('.actions input').attr('disabled', hasValue ? false : 'disabled');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <select id="position">
        <option value="">position</option>
        <option value="1">first</option>
        <option value="2">second</option>
        <option value="3">third</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: what browser you are using it's working fine with me?

Comment: i am using chrome

Comment: so what is not working for you? for me if any value from inputs or select is there the button will be enabled is that what you are looking for?

Comment: It is working sorry , The thing I misunderstood was , I just typed and looking for change but this happens after any outside or next click , Guess you might have observed the same

Comment: i modified the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `change` rather than `keyup`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.field input,.field select').change(function() {
    var hasValue = $('#username,#password,#position').filter((index, input ,select) => input.value.length > 0).length;

    $('.actions input').attr('disabled', hasValue ? false : 'disabled');
  });
});
```